# Deleting equal elements from a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

Can I check out if one single list has two or more equal elements and then delete them, even if I don't know what specific elements I'm looking for ?

Or check the different elements when comparing two lists, like A-B, in set theory. Getting elements in A that doesn't exist in B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the items, just use the Python `set` data type instead of lists:

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 3])
t = set([2, 4, 6])
print s
print t
print s - t
```

prints

```
set([1, 2, 3])
set([2, 4, 6])
set([1, 3])
```

Comment: And if you do care about the order, you can use an OrderedSet: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/

Answer (score 1):

For the `Or check ...` part of your questions:

```
In []: A, B= {1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 6, 8}
In []: A- B
Out[]: set([1, 3])
```

**Update** concerning the validity of used syntax:

```
In []: A, B= {1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 6, 8} # seems to be valid for 2.7 and above
# In []: A, B= set([1, 2, 3, 4]), set([2, 4, 6, 8]) # for 2.4 and above
In []: A- B # apparently since 2.4
Out[]: set([1, 3])
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention that this is Python 3.x -- most people still use 2.x

Comment: @Sven: Actually this is valid with 2.7.1. Although I don't seem to find any definite answer for; since what version: 1) sets can be defined by curly brackets, 2) instead of A.difference(B) you'll also able to use subtract operator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's an actual [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) builtin type that allows you to do things like `intersection()` and `union()`, but if you're dealing with a simple list and want the unique version of it, a fast and simple way of doing it is simply inserting them into a dictionary and taking the keys once you're done.

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
>>> d = {}
>>> for num in L:
    d[num] = None


>>> d.keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And if you're interested in order-preserving, then there's an interesting blog post exploring various ways of "uniquifying" a list both with and without order preservation [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark).

Comment: As of Python 2.4, `set`s are language built-ins, so using a dictionary seems quite outdated.

Comment: -1 Unless you're using an ancient version, this is about as pointless as defining a `list` ripoff atop of dictionaries...